# Clojure: Working on a filtered list of elements and recombining them with the rest of the list, Looking for more idiomatic solution

Tags: clojure

Say I have a function named `process`, that I would only like to apply to a subset of the elements of a sequence, `my-sequence` and then get back the original sequence with only the subset of the elements processed.

If I `(map process (filter my-pred my-sequence))`, I will only be left with the processed elements.

Instead I can `(map #(if (pred %) (process %) %) my-sequence)`.

Is there a more idiomatic/concise way to do this?

Comment: imo you got it as idiomatic as it gets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @soulcheck's comment that your solution is about is good as you'll get. However, there is one thing I'd suggest. I find that whenever I'm doing anything even remotely complex with `map`, it's usually more aesthetically pleasing to use a `for` instead. E.g.:

```
(map #(if (pred %) (process %) %) my-sequence)
```

becomes

```
(for [x my-sequence]
  (if (pred x) (process x) x))
```

Since both `map` and `for` produce lazy sequences, these should be equivalent.

Comment: Glad I asked, because I do think `for` is more readable in this case.